# Pandas group by with conditions

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a df with some retailer specific prices , i need to group and calculate avg prices on some conditions and add column on same df

example df

```
source  | price     | stock
abc     | 10        | in stock
def     | 12        | in stock
def     | 12        | in stock
abc     | 10        | out of stock
qwe     | 15        | in stock
qwe     | 15        | out of stock
qwe     | 13        | in stock
qwe     | 13        | in stock
```

condition

1. Considering abc as my base source i need to compare average price of abc with remaning onces
2. Should not include Out of stock product for any calculations

required output

```
source  | abc price    | comp price | price index
def     | 10           | 12         | 0.83
qwe     | 10           | 13.66      | 0.73
```

Here comp price is average of all rows for source def and qwe
in qwe we need to exclude out of stock and take avg of all in stock and populate in comp price

I have tried

```
.groupby(group_combination)['price'].transform('avg')
```

It didn't work

please help to get optimal solution

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. SO is a Q&A site, but this isn't a question. What do you need help with exactly? The task you're describing has a bunch of steps, but you seem to be stuck on one and you don't seem to have started on the others (like filtering out "out of stock" values, for one). So maybe it'd be best to ask just about the one you're stuck on. Please read [ask]. You might also want to read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4518341)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can use:

```
ref = 'abc'

out = (df.query('stock != "out of stock"')
         .groupby('source', as_index=False)['price'].mean()
         .assign(**{f'{ref} price': lambda d: d.set_index('source').loc[ref, 'price']})
         .rename(columns={'price': 'comp price'})
         .assign(**{'price index': lambda d: d['comp price'].rdiv(d[f'{ref} price'])})
         .loc[lambda d: d['source'].ne(ref)]
      )

print(out)
```

Output:

```
   source  comp price  abc price  price index
1     def   12.000000       10.0     0.833333
2     qwe   13.666667       10.0     0.731707
```

Comment: FWIW, I tried the problem myself and got basically the same solution, but using separate variables, which is a lot easier to follow for me. https://gist.github.com/wjandrea/c248fd3234fc409ee6cb993c074f8a76

Comment: @wjandrea yes, using intermediate variables often make things explicit as they act as some kind of documentation if the variable names are meaningful :)